# IOS How to automatically rezise its subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using IOS 5. I am a very beginner in IOS. In my project i have 2 xib files. One is a UIView and other is a UIViewcotroller. The UIViewcontroller is having 3 views(TopBar,ContentArea,BottomBar). uiview also has 3 subviews. I added UIView as subview of UIViewController. My requirement is change the UIView height when i hide topbar only, bottombar only, topbar and bottombar.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the views as properties,

`@property (nonatomic, retain)UIView *element1_p1;`

then when you need to change the size, change the frame,

```
self.element1_p1.frame = CGRectMake(center.x,
                                    center.y,
                                    elementWidth, elementHeight);
```

I recommend doing an animation for the change of height, so it feels better UX

[great tutorial for changing views properties with animation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation)

Answer (score 0):

UIView has method as `setFrame` to resize the view.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW10) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6) - you will get an idea how subviews respond to parent view's frame changes.